# Cursor of input button will cannot be set to pointer

Tags: html, css, pointers

I have the following CSS & HTML and yet the cursor when hovering over the button is of type `text`. The button lies on top of the search field so I guess that's why it reverts back to `text` but shouldn't the element-specific CSS override that and prevent the cursor from reverting back to `text`?

```
  form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px; 
  }
  #search-field {
     color: black;
     float: left;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 4px;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 12px;
     padding: 6px;
     padding-right: 47px;
   }

   #search-go {
      border: none;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 1px;
      margin-left: -39px;
      background-color: rgb(70, 65, 65);
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    } 

    <form onsubmit="return false;">
       <input id="search-field" type="text" placeholder="search">
       <input id="search-go" type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/84pPg/) but the problem is that the button is mostly hidden. The part that isn't hidden, though, does have the had cursor. So I'm afraid there's more to your problem than you're showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 input[type=file] {
  cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: type=file? That doesn't occur in the question. Also, never use cursor:hand. It is an error and it's never necessary. Even IE6 supported cursor:pointer!